# Linux Taskset Command: Setting 100% CPU Usage for Mutiple Processes

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cpu-speed

Currently have a data-intensive process running on Ubuntu Version 11.04 that needs multiple CPU usage.

I wrote the command, given I have 4 cores

```
taskset -c 0,1,2,3 python sample.py
```

I am only achieving 100% on one CPU, and the others are idle <2%.

Any tips how to ramp all 4 CPUs up to 100% to make the task faster?

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You will have to show a simplified version of `sample.py` to get effective help.

Answer (score 0):

Application needs to be prepared to use more than one core, its tasks need to be divided into separate threads. Otherwise there is little to no usage of more than one CPU.

Comment: See the other answer. Python's GIL prevents multithreading from effectively using multiple CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

Standard python interpreter (CPython) has [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) that prevents running more than one thread on a CPU. Consider using `multiprocessing` module or use alternative implementations such as [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).